# find all ocurrences inside a list

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite, list-comprehension

I'm trying to implement a function to find occurrences in a list, here's my code:

```
def all_numbers():
    num_list = []
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM myTable")
    for row in c:
        num_list.append(row[1])
    return num_list

def compare_results():
    look_up_num = raw_input("Lucky number: ")
    occurrences = [i for i, x in enumerate(all_numbers()) if x == look_up_num]
    return occurrences
```

I keep getting an empty list instead of the ocurrences even when I enter a number that is on the mentioned list.

Comment: what you are getting in all_numbers()?

Comment: @cracker I was getting an empty list but I just figured out thanks to the community. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does the following:

1. It fetches everything from the database. Each row is a *sequence*.
2. Then, it takes all these results and adds them to a list.
3. It returns this list.
4. Next, your code goes through each item list (remember, its a *sequence*, like a tuple) and fetches the item and its index (this is what enumerate does).
5. Next, you attempt to compare the *sequence* with a string, and if it matches, return it as part of a list.

At #5, the script fails because you are comparing a *tuple* to a string. Here is a simplified example of what you are doing:

```
>>> def all_numbers():
...     return [(1,5), (2,6)]
...
>>> lucky_number = 5
>>> for i, x in enumerate(all_numbers()):
...     print('{} {}'.format(i, x))
...     if x == lucky_number:
...         print 'Found it!'
...
0 (1, 5)
1 (2, 6)
```

As you can see, at each loop, your `x` is the tuple, and it will never equal `5`; even though actually the row exists.

You can have the database do your dirty work for you, by returning only the number of rows that match your lucky number:

```
def get_number_count(lucky_number):
    """ Returns the number of times the lucky_number
        appears in the database """

    c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE number_column = %s', (lucky_number,))
    result = c.fetchone()
    return result[0]

def get_input_number():
    """ Get the number to be searched in the database """
    lookup_num = raw_input('Lucky number: ')
    return get_number_count(lookup_num)
```

Comment: great answer! It solved my problem and also it helped me with other stuff I was stuck into. Thanks man, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

raw_input is returning a string.  Try converting it to a number.

```
 occurrences = [i for i, x in enumerate(all_numbers()) if x == int(look_up_num)]
```

Comment: thanks for the headsup, I wasn't aware that I was comparing two different things